# ANTLR4-based lexer loses syntax hightlighting during typing on NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, syntax-highlighting, antlr4, lexer

I've coded a simple lexer and parser using *ANTLR4 grammars* to make a language plugin for NetBeans 7.3 to help team write more quickly our layout files (a mix of XHTML and widgets definitions also in form of XHTML tags but with custom properties, characteristics, and with some differencies against XHTML syntax).

Template file example:

```
<div style="dyn_layout_panel">
    @symbol@
    <w_label=label, text="Try to close this window" />
    <w_buttonclose=button, text = "CLOSE", on_press=press_close />
    <w_buttonterminate=button, text="TERMINATE", on_press=press_terminate />
    <w_mydatepicker=datepicker, parent=tab0, ary=[10, "str", /regex/i], start_date=2013-10-05, on_selected=datepicker_selected />
    <w_myeditbox=editbox, parent=tab0, validation=USER_REGEX, validation_regex=/^[0-9]+[a-z]*$/i,
        validation_msg="User regex don't match editbox contents.", on_keyreturn=tab0_editbox_keyreturn />
    <div style="dyn_layout_panel">
        $SYMBOL_2$
        Some text that make a text node.
    </div>
</div>
```

I use AnltrWorks 2 to write and debug lexer and parser and all seem to be fine, in NetBeans also I don't get any exception and the parser work properly but **during editing/typing I lose token colors near the cursor.**

Screenshot of problem:

[image]

Adding a debug console output for each keystroke I see that the lexer enter in **IN_TAG** or **IN_WIDGET** mode correctly, but after a **WHITESPACE** it returns to the default mode and match te rest of text inside a tag as a **TEXT_NODE** token.

I know that a lexer can have only **one active mode at a time**, so because it matches the TEXT_NODE rule when in IN_TAG or IN_WIDGET modes?

Lexer grammar file:

```
lexer grammar LayoutLexer;

COMMENT
    :   '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | EOL
        )+? -> channel(HIDDEN)
        ;

WDG_START_OPEN : '<w_' PROPERTY -> pushMode(IN_WIDGET) ;
WDG_END_OPEN : '</w_' PROPERTY -> pushMode(IN_WIDGET) ;
TAG_START_OPEN : '<' ATTRIBUTE -> pushMode(IN_TAG) ;
TAG_END_OPEN : '</' ATTRIBUTE -> pushMode(IN_TAG) ;

EXT_REF
    :   ( ('@' REF_NAME '@') | ('$' SYMBOL '$') | ('§' REF_NAME '§') )
    ;

fragment
REF_NAME
    :   ( [a-z]+ [0-9a-z_]*? )
    ;

fragment
EOL :   ( '\r\n' | '\n\r' | '\n' )
    ;

EQUAL
    :   '='
    ;

TEXT_NODE
    :   ( (~('\r'|'\n'|'<'|'@'|'$'|'§'))+ )
    ;

ERROR
    :   ( .+? )
    ;

mode IN_TAG;

TAG_CLOSE : '>' -> popMode ;
TAG_EMPTY_CLOSE : '/>' -> popMode ;

TAG_WS : WS -> type(WS), channel(HIDDEN) ;
TAG_COMMENT : COMMENT -> type(COMMENT), channel(HIDDEN) ;

TAG_EQ : EQUAL -> type(EQUAL) ;

ATTRIBUTE
    :   ( LITERAL [0-9a-zA-Z_]* )
    ;

VAL
    :  ( '"' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'"') )*? '"'
    |  '\'' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'\'') )*? '\'' )
    ;

TAG_ERR : ERROR -> type(ERROR) ;

mode IN_WIDGET;

WDG_CLOSE : '>' -> popMode ;
WDG_EMPTY_CLOSE : '/>' -> popMode ;

WDG_WS : WS -> type(WS), mode(IN_WIDGET), channel(HIDDEN) ;
WDG_COMMENT : COMMENT -> type(COMMENT), channel(HIDDEN) ;

WDG_EQ : EQUAL -> type(EQUAL), pushMode(WDG_ASSIGN) ;

COMMA
    :   ','
    ;

fragment
MINUS
    :   '-'
    ;

STRING
    :  ( '"' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'"') )*? '"'
    |  '\'' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'\'') )*? '\'' )
    ;

fragment
ESC_SEQ
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    |   UNICODE_ESC
    |   OCTAL_ESC
    ;

fragment
OCTAL_ESC
    :   '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7')
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
    :   '\\' 'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT
    ;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT
    :   [0-9a-fA-F]
    ;

fragment
DIGIT
    :   [0-9]
    ;

fragment
HEX_NUMBER
    :   '0x' HEX_DIGIT+
    ;

fragment
HTML_NUMBER
    :   (INT_NUMBER | FLOAT_NUMBER) HTML_UNITS
    ;

fragment
FLOAT_NUMBER
    :   MINUS? INT_NUMBER '.' DIGIT+
    ;

fragment
INT_NUMBER
    :   MINUS? DIGIT+
    ;

EVENT_HANDLER
    :   'on_' PROPERTY
    ;

PROPERTY
    :   ( LITERAL [0-9a-zA-Z_]* )
    ;

fragment
LITERAL 
    :   ( LITERAL_U | LITERAL_L )
    ;

fragment
LITERAL_U
    :   [A-Z]+
    ;

fragment
LITERAL_L
    :   [a-z]+
    ;

WDG_ERR : ERROR -> type(ERROR) ;

mode WDG_ASSIGN;

PHP_REF
    : ( LITERAL_L ('_' | LITERAL_L | [0-9])* ) -> popMode
    ;

VALUE : (WDG_VAL | ARRAY) -> popMode;

ASGN_WS : WS -> type(WS), channel(HIDDEN);
ASGN_COMMA : COMMA -> type(COMMA);

ARY_START
    :   '[' 
    ;

ARY_END
    :   ']'
    ;

BIT_OR
    :   '|'
    ;

ARRAY
    :   ARY_START ARY_VALUE (ASGN_COMMA ARY_VALUE)* ARY_END
    ;

fragment
ARY_VALUE : ASGN_WS? WDG_VAL ASGN_WS? -> type(VALUE);

fragment
WDG_VAL
    :   (STRING
    |   UTC_DATE
    |   HEX_NUMBER
    |   HTML_NUMBER
    |   FLOAT_NUMBER
    |   INT_NUMBER
    |   BOOLEAN
    |   BITFIELD
    |   REGEX
    |   CSS_CLASS)
    ;

fragment
HTML_UNITS
    :   ('%'|'in'|'cm'|'mm'|'em'|'ex'|'pt'|'pc'|'px')
    ;

fragment
BOOLEAN
    :   ('true'|'false')
    ;

fragment
BITFIELD
    :   SYMBOL (WS? BIT_OR WS? SYMBOL)*
    ;

SYMBOL
    :   LITERAL_U [0-9A-Z_]*
    ;

UTC_DATE
    :   (DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT)
    ;

REGEX
    : ('/' ('\\'.|.)*? '/' ('g'|'m'|'i')* )
    ;

CSS_CLASS
    : ( LITERAL_L ('-' | '_' | LITERAL_L | [0-9])* )
    ;

WDG_ASSIGN_ERR : ERROR -> type(ERROR), popMode;
```

Parser grammar file:

```
parser grammar LayoutParser;

options 
{
    tokenVocab=LayoutLexer;
    language=Java;
}

document : (element | TEXT_NODE | EXT_REF)* EOF;

element
locals
[
    String currentTag
]
    : ( ( html_open_tag (element | TEXT_NODE | EXT_REF)* html_close_tag )
    | ( wdg_open_tag (element | TEXT_NODE | EXT_REF)* wdg_close_tag )
    | ( html_empty_tag | wdg_empty_tag ) )
    ;

html_empty_tag
    : TAG_START_OPEN (ATTRIBUTE EQUAL VAL)* TAG_EMPTY_CLOSE
    ;

html_open_tag
    : ( tag=TAG_START_OPEN (ATTRIBUTE EQUAL VAL)* TAG_CLOSE )
        {$element::currentTag = $tag.text.substring(1);}
    ;

html_close_tag
    : tag=TAG_END_OPEN TAG_CLOSE
        {
            if (!$element::currentTag.equals($tag.text.substring(2)))
                notifyErrorListeners("HTML tag mismatch '" + $element::currentTag + "' - '" + $tag.text.substring(2) + "'");
        }
    ;

wdg_empty_tag
    : WDG_START_OPEN EQUAL PHP_REF ( COMMA (wdg_prop | wdg_event) )* WDG_EMPTY_CLOSE
    ;

wdg_open_tag
    : tag=WDG_START_OPEN EQUAL PHP_REF ( COMMA (wdg_prop | wdg_event) )* WDG_CLOSE
        {$element::currentTag = $tag.text.substring(1);}
    ;

wdg_close_tag
    : tag=WDG_END_OPEN WDG_CLOSE
        {
            if (!$element::currentTag.equals($tag.text.substring(2)))
                notifyErrorListeners("Widget alias mismatch '" + $element::currentTag + "' - '" + $tag.text + "'");
        }
    ;

wdg_prop
    : PROPERTY (EQUAL (ARRAY | VALUE | PHP_REF | UTC_DATE | REGEX | CSS_CLASS))?
    ;

wdg_event
    : EVENT_HANDLER EQUAL PHP_REF
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the implementation of syntax highlighting, the IDE may or may not start at the beginning of the document when lexing the input for syntax highlighting. If it does not start at the beginning of the document, then before returning any tokens, you need to ensure that the lexer instance is initialized in the correct mode (both the [`_mode`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Lexer.html#_mode) and [`_modeStack`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Lexer.html#_modeStack) fields need to be initialized to their correct state at the point where lexing starts).

If your lexer reads or writes any custom fields during lexing, you may need to restore those fields as well.

#### Examples

- GoWorks (NetBeans based, LGPL License). This implementation *does not* use the lexer facilities in the NetBeans API, but instead implements the functionality at a lower level. For now you can ignore the `MarkOccurrences*` and `SemanticHighlighter` classes.

  - [package org.tvl.goworks.editor.go.highlighter](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/goworks/tree/master/goworks.editor/src/org/tvl/goworks/editor/go/highlighter)
  - [package org.antlr.works.editor.antlr4.highlighting](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/goworks/tree/master/works.editor.antlr4/src/org/antlr/works/editor/antlr4/highlighting)
- ANTLR 4 IntelliJ Plugin (IntelliJ IDEA, BSD license).

  - [package org.antlr.intellij.adaptor.lexer](https://github.com/antlr/intellij-plugin-v4/tree/master/src/adaptor/org/antlr/intellij/adaptor/lexer)
  - [package org.antlr.intellij.plugin](https://github.com/antlr/intellij-plugin-v4/tree/master/src/java/org/antlr/intellij/plugin) (in particular, the SyntaxHighlighter classes)

#### Additional efficiency notes

- Your `REF_NAME`, `VAL`, and `STRING` rules use non-greedy loops that do not need to be non-greedy. In each of these rules, change `+?` to `+` and change `*?` to `*`.
- Your `WS` and `ERROR` rules use a non-greedy operator `+?` which is equivalent to not having a closure at all. The unnecessary use of a non-greedy operator in these cases only serves to slow down your lexer. To preserve the existing behavior, you can remove `+?` from these rules (replacing with `+` would change behavior).

#### Additional functionality notes

- ANTLR 4 does not perform any error correction during lexing. If the input does not match a token, then the input simply does not match a token. This issue affects your `VAL` and `STRING` tokens in particular, which will not get syntax highlighting prior to adding the closing `"` or `'` character. For syntax highlighting these types of tokens, I prefer to use an additional mode in the lexer, allowing me to produce separate tokens for the escape sequences embedded in the string, as well as syntax highlighting an unterminated string at the end of the line (unless your language allows strings to span multiple lines, in which case you'd stop at the end of the input).

Comment: I perfectly understand what you mean, thanks for your hints about grammar rules. I will try to set correct mode from current cursor position (I'm really new to ANTLR and NetBeans platform). Sorry but I don't have enough rep to up-vote.

Comment: I've already seen the code of links above and I almost ended on a solution using `token.getStopIndex()`. I have only a last question, is possible with ANTLR lexer to go back/forward from current position to a known token (if exist)? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

**For future references**

All problems are related to the wrong implementation I done of NetBeans `Lexer<T>` class; many tutorials on the web do not take into account that **a lexer may have more than one mode** and that the lexer state must be backuped and restored between Lexer allocation/releases *as mentioned by 280Z28*.

This is the code I use to make syntax highlighting consistent:

```
public class LayoutEditorLexer implements Lexer<LayoutTokenId> {

    private LexerRestartInfo<LayoutTokenId> info;
    private LayoutLexer lexer;

    private class LexerState {
        public int Mode = -1;
        public IntegerStack Stack = null;
        public LexerState(int mode, IntegerStack stack)
        {
            Mode = mode;
            Stack = new IntegerStack(stack);
        }
    }

    public LayoutEditorLexer(LexerRestartInfo<LayoutTokenId> info) {
        this.info = info;

        AntlrCharStream charStream = new AntlrCharStream(info.input(), "LayoutEditor", false);
        lexer = new LayoutLexer(charStream);
        lexer.removeErrorListeners();
        lexer.addErrorListener(ErrorListener.INSTANCE);
        LexerState lexerMode = (LexerState)info.state();
        if (lexerMode != null)
        {
            lexer._mode = lexerMode.Mode;
            lexer._modeStack.addAll(lexerMode.Stack);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public org.netbeans.api.lexer.Token<LayoutTokenId> nextToken() {
        Token token = lexer.nextToken();
        int ttype = token.getType();

        if (ttype != LayoutLexer.EOF)
        {
            LayoutTokenId tokenId = LayoutLanguageHierarchy.getToken(ttype);
            return info.tokenFactory().createToken(tokenId);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object state()
    {
        // Here many tutorials simply returns null.
        return new LexerState(lexer._mode, lexer._modeStack);
    }

    @Override
    public void release()
    {
    }
}
```